# What processing power in a laptop do I need to output 1080p video?

Tags: laptop, video, cpu, gpu, 1080p

Will the AMD or Intel integrated GPU have enough power to drive blu ray movie without stutter, or do I need to look for laptop with a dedicated graphics card? Does it make any difference if CPU is duel core, i.e. 2nd or 3rd gen i3 is adequate as compared to i5?

Looking to output (wirelessly 802.11n) to 55 inch tv with least expensive quality build laptop.

Comment: Some of this depends on software, but even many of the Atom processors used in netbooks a few years ago were able to handle 1080p playback.  Most anything modern should be able to handle this.

Comment: If you're doing any kind of wireless display (which is sounds like you are), you will require much beefier specs - something is capable of real-time H.264 encode at 1080p

Answer (score 1):

Even a [Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/) can [playback 1080p](http://wiki.xbmc.org/?title=Raspberry_Pi/FAQ#Output). Unless you are using some really horrible old laptop, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Best is to go and read about the specs of the laptop and see if that video format is supported. Newer laptops (2008 +) would definitely not be problem